# QtCreator + MSVS2012. Не запускается Debug-версия проекта

Tags: qtcreator, qt, visual-studio-2012

Есть проект на C++/Qt. Используется компилятор MSVS2012 в связке с QtCreator.
При попытке запуска с Debug-версией (как с отладчиком, так и без) дает вывод :

> Запускается C:\Project_path\Project-build-path-Debug\debug\Project_name.exe...
>   Не удалось запустить программу. Путь или права недопустимы?
>   C:\Project_path\Project-build-path-Debug\debug\Project_name.exe завершился с кодом -1

З.Ы. Кириллицы в путях нет. Перенос исходников в новый проект дает тот же результат. Релизная сборка запускается без нареканий. Поиск дает расплывчатые ответы. Есть ли идеи у уважаемого сообщества, куда копать?

Comment: А там чего-нибудь интересного в других табах нету случайно? То что вы привели очевидно из вывода приложения, а вот вывод компилятора/дебагера и ко у криэйтора стоит отдельно насколько помню.

Comment: а ручками бинарник запускается?

Comment: Проверьте, установлены ли у Вас WinDbg (Debugger Tools for Windows)  (http://www.windbg.org)?